# Passing "and" word in query string value in .aspx page is resetting server's connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Asp.Net, C# and IIS8 server. When I try to Pass "and" word in query string value in .aspx page, it is resetting server's connection. For example when I tried to navigate to url like `www.test.com/test.aspx?str=a%20and%20b`, server connection is reset immediately.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: i got message in mozilla that "The connection was reset"

Comment: I don't know what you mean with _reset_ but for sure **you can't use spaces in URL**. It should be `www.test.com/test.aspx?str=a%20and%20b`

Comment: i have edited the question i agreed it just a typo, but the same problem

Comment: Can you show how do you use that URL?

Comment: the resulting url is formed like www.test.com/test.aspx?str=a%20and%20b, forgive me for any misunderstanding

Comment: Can you please post what you do in your test.aspx page? Where do you use that parameter? I highly doubt _IIS_ crashes because you pass "and" in your URL...

Comment: actually it's a network issue firewall is blocking the url. anyways thanks everyone for the help.